# No white page before full pdf page as front cover. (title page)

Tags: page-breaking, titles, pdfpages

I have a little problem with a pdf that I want as front cover for a report. When I add a pdf as front cover I get first a white page and after that the pdf. But I want it to print the pdf first than white page and after that the title page. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

PreTitle page code

```
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

\includepdf[scale=1.0]{0_Title_Page/Voorkant.pdf}

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
```

Final code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[monochrome]{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
  \geometry{a4paper}
    \geometry{width=0.7\paperwidth,height=0.8\paperheight}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}             % For sideways figures
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{url}                                    % URL package
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
%\usepackage{titlesec}                      % Change space between title and text, if needed
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{eurosym}                            % Euro symbol
\usepackage{gensymb}                            % Degree symbol
\usepackage{appendix}                       % Appendix packages!!!
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{booktabs}                       % For toprule, middlerule & bottomrule
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}
\usepackage{footnote}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt} 

%\renewcommand\enoteformat{\noindent\theenmark.\hspace{0.06in}} % change superscript to 1.
%\let\footnote=\endnote % Trun footnotes to ENDnotes

%\usepackage{mcode}         %When adding matlab code!!!

%\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
%  {\bfseries\Huge}
%  {\filright\Large\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}
%  {0mm}{\filright}
%\titlespacing*{\chapter}
%  {0pt}{-10pt}{0pt} % als je de 3de veranderd kun je de spacing tussen het hoofdstuk en tekst kleiner maken.

\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 `dirname #1`/`basename #1 .tif`.png}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\begin{document}

\input{0_Title_Page/PreTitle} % front cover

\cleardoublepage

\input{0_Title_Page/TitlePage} %'real' title page
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the `center` environment; `\includepdf` will center the page anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The `\includepdf` generates a new page by itself. You seem to have some code which adds some (invisible) material before it which got already placed on the current page. Therefore this page is first flushed out before the PDF is included. In general, to solve this remove the code which causes this before the `\includepdf`. In your case the extra page is caused by the `center` environment which uses a list environment internally (`trivlist`). You should avoid using `center` with images in general (e.g. with `figure`). It is intended for text paragraphs and adds an extra vertical space before and after it.